# How to authenticate proxy in manifest v3 for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am developing a proxy extension and everything is done but last my proxy IP need to authenticate with username and password it was easy in manifest v2 but in manifest v3 I am not able to find a way, please help.

**manifest v3**

```
"declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [{
      "id": "ruleset_1",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "rules.json"
    }]
},
"permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "background",
        "declarativeNetRequest",
        "webRequest",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",      
        "cookies",
        "browsingData",
        "webNavigation",
        "privacy",
        "scripting" 
    ]
```

**Rules.json**

```
[
  {
   "id": 1, 
   "priority": 1, 
   "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders", 
      "responseHeaders": [
        {"header": "Proxy-Authenticate", "operation": "append", "value": "Seladnaneren8676:A2x1CfW"}
      ]
   }, 
   "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "*",
      "resourceTypes": ["document"]
   }
}
]
```

Comment: There's no way yet, https://crbug.com/1135492.